# Error related to Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning Excel Macro, I've recorded a simple macro in which there are 8 observations and it's calculating average of the observation and then calculating difference from average. 
The code is as follows:

```
Sub Bias1()
'
' Bias1 Macro
'

'
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-8]C:R[-1]C)"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-R10C2"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C9"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C2:C9").Select
    Range("C10").Select
End Sub
```

I am trying to run this code in an Excel spreadsheet (I was using it for practice therefore a number of other macros too are present) it is throwing the following error at the line Range("B10").Select:
**Compile Error:
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment**

But when I am running the same piece of code in a fresh Excel file it is running fine, giving the expected outcome.

Kindly let help me understand why this error is coming in one excel and working in other.

Thanks for the response in anticipation.

Comment: The range is clean in the new sheet.  In the other sheet, B10 is not what is expected.  It's probably got another cell merged with it.  Wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I got the root cause of the error message. I mistakenly created another Macro with name Range(), hence throwing an error. Thanks again.